# Incorrect time inside kernel space using ktime_get_real_ts64

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel module (LKM) and need to print correct time. This is my code:

```
static int __init modtime_init(void) {

printk("Entering: %s\n",__FUNCTION__);


//************************time k****************************************************************
struct timespec64 time;
unsigned long local_time;
struct rtc_time tm;
ktime_get_real_ts64(&time);
local_time = time.tv_sec - (sys_tz.tz_minuteswest * 60);
rtc_time_to_tm(local_time, &tm);

printk("date and time: (%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d)\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
}
```

The problem is dmesg print all right except for hour. In fact, tm.tm_hour is less two hours than my local time. In other words the output is 10:00 instead of 12:00. Output of the command "date" from userspace is also correct. Is there something wrong about my code?

Comment: `is less two hours than my local time` so, in which timezone you are? Do you understand what is the difference between local time and UTC? `Output of the command "date"` Please post the output from `date`.

Comment: Using the command from terminal < date +"%Z %z" >, the output is CEST +0200. Date command is "ven 10 lug 2020, 10.02.10, CEST"

Comment: You most probably have `sys_tz.tz_minuteswest = 0` which means your machine's timezone is set to UTC.

Comment: In fact, if I put sys_tz.tz_minuteswest=-120; it works. But I did think there was a connection between kernel space and user space timezone

Comment: I think `sys_tz` is obsolete. Also, it is normal for the kernel to use UTC internally.